# how to install LDOCE5 in ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Tags: software-installation

I download the iso file if longman dictionary. I follow the structure and did everything in help file.
but when I click on the desktop icon , it's just lunched without anything particular. then nothing happen
need your help

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the links to the instructions your are following and where you got such *iso file*?

Answer (score 0):

### To install [LDOCE5 Viewer](https://forward-backward.co.jp/ldoce5viewer/)

**Prerequisites**

- Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English 5th Edition (DVD-ROM)
- Python 2.7 or 2.6 (or 3.x)
- Development tools for PyQt4:

  - `pyqt4-dev-tools`
- lxml:

  - `python-lxml`
- Whoosh 2.x:

  - `python-whoosh`

    If you are on Ubuntu 15+, the default python-whoosh to be installed is 2.7.0+, which may cause error with the application during index. Therefore,you have 2 options :

    Use pip to install python whoosh 2.5.python-pip pip install whoosh==2.5.7

    Install .deb file from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/python-whoosh/download) to grab the old version (2.5.7) of python-whoosh.
- Python bindings for Gstreamer:

  - `python-gst0.10`
- Gstreamer plugins for MP3 audio playback:

  - `gstreamer0.10-plugins-good & gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`

If you're using Ubuntu 15.x, you should install `python-qt4-phonon` to pronunce words and sentences correctly.

---

### Installation

**1.** Download these two packages [ldoce5viewer](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ldoce5viewer/) and [ldoce5viewer-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ldoce5viewer-git/) from Archlinux User Repository.

**2.** Open a terminal, and `cd /path/to/the/downloaded/files`

**3.** Enter the following commands in the terminal:

- `make build`
- `sudo make install`

**4.** Copy the `ldoce5.data` directory from the LDOCE5 DVD-ROM to an arbitrary location in your HDD or SSD.

**5.** Start the LDOCE5 Viewer.

**6.** The application will ask you the location where you put `ldoce5.data`.

---

**Sources:**

https://forward-backward.co.jp/ldoce5viewer/

https://github.com/ciscorn/ldoce5viewer

Comment: I remove and install again. this time , first I install python-whoosh.deb and installed it first , then run the commands in terminal like this: 
linux32 ./setup.sh
after installing, the error occured `.fonts/AWLPhonetics3U.TTF': Permission denied`
I change the permission of desktop.icon to executable but in vain.
after clicking on the icon , longman lunched but after a few secs, disappeared.

Comment: You may need to run it as root, tun it with `sudo`

Comment: I did it but in vain

Comment: Im afarid I cant really understand what you mean. Can you try again?